# Python setuptools: How can I add a private repository (gitlab) in my setup.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, gitlab, package

I have 2 package uploaded which are in my gitlab repository, if I want to install them in my system using pip, it's easy because gitlab helps you:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/index.html

```
pip install <package-name> --extra-index-url https://<username>:<your_personal_token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project ID>/packages/pypi/simple
```

**the name of those two package:**

- core_1
- service_1

What I want it's to create other package where it download those two private package and I need to configurate in setup.py:

**this is my setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
name='my_project',
version='0.1.0',
packages=find_packages(),
package_data = {
    'config':['*.yaml']
    },
include_package_data=True,
install_requires=[
    'click', 
    'colorama',
    'core_1 --extra-index-url https://joelbarrantespalacios:<personal_token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_ID>/packages/pypi/simple',
    'service_1 --extra-index-url https://joelbarrantespalacios:<personal_token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_ID>/packages/pypi/simple'
],
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'darit = core_project.cli:start',
    ],
},
```

)

of course, **<personal_token> and <project_ID>** needs to be add however I'm not giving you because it's a private package.

**joelbarrantespalacios**: it's my username

this is what I found in setuptools's Documentation where it shows how to create a Dependencies that aren’t in PyPI, but it's not clear for me

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html

**I really need you helps guys, give me some hope.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the index/authentication information to a `pip.cfg` file or `~/.pypirc` file.

Using a `~/.pypirc` file:

```
[gitlab]
repository = https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi
username = <username>
password = <token>
```

Where `<token>` is an API token with API scope. Alternatively, provide the index/auth information to `pip` when installing your packages.

Your `setup.py` dependencies should simply declare the name of the package. e.g.

```py
# ...
install_requires=[
    'core_1',
    'service_1',
#...
```

`pip` will resolve it from the configured registries in your `pip.cfg` or `.pypirc` file (or `pip` CLI options) automatically.

Your `setup.py` gets bundled with your package when it is uploaded to the registry and is downloaded by its users, so it obviously shouldn't contain sensitive information like your passwords/tokens anyhow!

Comment: yeah, when i ask this question, i've made a mistake 'cause i tried to install 'my_project' compiled in my system and I hoped it installs core_1 and service_1, of course i didn't upload 'my_project' to PyPI.                                                                                                                                                afterwards, I uploaded 'my_project' to PyPI and then It just installs core_1 and service_1.                    PD: we need to pu this in setup.py
 install_requires=[
    'core_1',
    'service_1']