# Listing a package from GitLab's package registry as a dependency in package metadata

Tags: gitlab, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, requirements.txt

## Context

I currently have 2 private  repositories containing each a python package. For example: **pkg_a**, **pkg_b**

The package **pkg_b** need **pkg_a** inside his requirements.txt and setup.py file to be able to work.

###### Environment

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.0
- Pip 23.0.1

## My problem

I am not able to package **pkg_b** with the private package **pkg_a** as a dependency because install_requires inside setup.py of **pkg_b** does not like the format of my requirements.txt :

requirements.txt *(pkg_b)*

```
matplotlib==3.5.2
numpy==1.21.6
--extra-index-url https://__token__:<token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project>/packages/pypi/simple
pkg_a
```

setup.py *(pkg_b)*

```
def load_requirements(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fp:
        reqs = filter(None, (parse_req_line(line) for line in fp))
        return list(reqs)

setup(
    name='pkg_b',
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=install_requires,
    ...
)
```

Installing **pkg_b**

`python .\setup.py install`

Output

`error in pkg_b setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Parse error at "'--extra-'": Expected W:(abcd...)`

(this is expected because load_requirements() does not deal with --extra-index-url)

## What works

Installing the **pkg_a** from the requirements.txt inside a virtual environment :

powershell

```
python -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --no-input -r .\requirements.txt
```

pip list

```
...
matplotlib      3.5.2
numpy           1.21.6
pkg_a           1.0.0
...
```

Everything works when I run a python script of **pkg_b** that imports **pkg_a**

## What I tried

- Using pip's [VCS support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/) for git
  (does not work because I am using the package registry)
- Using a .pypirc like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70534764)
- Using dependency_links of setup.py or setting up a different config file like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701434)

## Usefull documentation

- [PyPI packages in the Package Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/)

Some people said it's not impossible some people said it is, but I can't find a working solution. Let's unite together and find an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get such `requirements.txt` content into the package metadata. Technically as well as conceptually package metadata can not contain `--extra-index-url` and other things like that.

I recommend you read this:

- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/

In the `install_requires` parameter of `setuptools.setup()` function call of the `setup.py` script, you should list simply `pkg_a` as an *abstract* dependency requirement. More concrete details about this dependency do not belong in the package metadata, they do not belong in `install_requires`. It's as simple as that.

I also recommend to read these:

- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1951#issuecomment-1430917786
- https://discuss.python.org/t/examples-of-why-parsing-requirements-txt-files-to-feed-project-metadata-is-a-bad-idea/24828

---

What you can do is instruct users of your code to install directly from a `requirements.txt` file that contains the more concrete dependency requirements. For example in your documentation, you can give the recommendation of installing via a command such as this:

```
python -m pip install https://host.dev/path/to/requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! The links you provided are very useful for what I'm doing right now.