# Adding --find-links URLs to dependencies in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, dependency-management, jax, pyproject.toml

You can install the python package [Jax](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/setup.py) with some extra packages depending on your environment.

For GPU:

```
pip install jax[cuda] --find-links https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
```

For TPU:

```
pip install jax[tpu]  --find-links https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/libtpu_releases.html
```

How do I add those `--find-links` URLs to the following `pyproject.toml`?

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=67.6.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "minimal_example"
version = '0.0.1'
requires-python = ">=3.9"

dependencies = [
    "seqio-nightly[gcp,cache-tasks]",
    "t5[gcp]",
    "t5x @ git+https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git"
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
cpu = ["jax[cpu]"]
gpu = ["jax[cuda]" , "t5x[gpu] @ git+https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git"]
tpu = ["jax[tpu]", "t5x[tpu] @ git+https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git"]
dev = ["pytest", "mkdocs"]
```

If I do `pip install -e .` then I get a working install.
But doing a `pip install -e ".[gpu]` gives me a `ResolutionImpossible` error.
And doing `pip install -e ".[tpu]` gives me:

```
Packages installed from PyPI cannot depend on packages which are not also hosted on PyPI.
jax depends on libtpu-nightly@ https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-tpu-tpuvm-artifacts/wheels/libtpu-nightly/libtpu_nightly-0.1.dev20210615-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Same answer as for this other recent question, you can't and you shouldn't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75799554