Setting dependencies in pyproject.toml for `pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.1.0+cpu.html`
I am writing a setup script pyproject.toml and need to include dependencies for a package that could be installed with pip like this: pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.1.0+cpu.html. How to do that? Usual tricks like @ does not work for this case.

This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75802128/7721752

I did get this to work by specifying the full url to the wheel file in the pyproject.toml file. e.g. dependencies = ["torch-scatter @ https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.1.0%2Bcpu/torch_scatter-2.1.2%2Bpt21cpu-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl"] 
